# Manually Editing Wordpress themes

Tags: wordpress

I have just started using Wordpress for building websites, mainly because I want my Clients to be able to edit the websites themselves after I have built it...

Now I don't want to just install a theme and use it, I want to customize the theme and put in my own plugins etc, maybe even rewrite some of the pages with pure HTML/CSS.

Now if I do this, will my clients still be able to use the user-friendly page editor to update content, or need I stick to the theme to enable that (without editing the theme)?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the theme (or building your own) will not affect the admin panel. They will be able to edit and write pages and posts just like always.

Comment: So doesn't matter what custom HTML/Javascript/CSS I use, the admin panel will enable 'user-friendly' editing?

Comment: That's right. Your theme will only affect the font side of the website, it will not change the backend (admin panel).